# Passing parameters to Custom control ViewModel, MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls, viewmodel

I am declaring a custom control within a view. The Control has its own ViewModel which I am declaring within the parent view's XAML. I would like to pass a value into this child ViewModel by binding but I am not using a dependency property and would rather not. Is there a way to go about this? or am I going to need a hefty rework?

Declaration of the child ViewModel including the binding that does not work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <uc:PagerViewModel x:Key="PagerDataContext" PagesContent="{Binding DisplayedRawData}">
    </uc:PagerViewModel>
<Window.Resources>
```

Declaration of custom control:

```
   <uc:Pager Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{StaticResource PagerDataContext }"/>
```

Child ViewModel relivent Code:

```
    public string PagesContent
    {
        get
        {
            return _pagesContent;
        }
        set
        {
            _pagesContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PagesContent");
        }
    }
    private string _pagesContent = string.Empty;
```

Comment: I know how to do it but not with resources. It's when you set your controls DataContext ViewModel and then do a Binding relativesource. :)

Comment: Sure, that could work. I do really like the idea of declaring my ViewModels as xaml resources though. If I am unable to come up with a different solution that is probably what i will do.

Comment: Well, I would actually use Caliburn.Micro library to hook up my ViewModels to the controls instead of using Resources. TBH, I don't see the benefit of it besides using it with CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 0):

Any binding target has to be a dependency property -- you can't bind *to* a view-model property.  One alternative approach, based on what you've presented, is to create a dependency property on the *view*, and then pass it along to the view-model that way:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <uc:PagerViewModel x:Key="PagerDataContext" />
<Window.Resources>
```

So, declare the dependency property `DisplayedRawData` in the `uc:Pager` control; inside its `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, pass the new value along to the view model:

```
((PagerViewModel)DataContext).PagesContent = DisplayedRawData
```